# Unable to do intersection of graphs in igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to find the intersection of multiple graphs in igraph. But when I run

```
intersection(g1, g2, g3, byname = T, keep.all.vertices=F)
```

it produces the following error

```
Error in `-.igraph`(g, setdiff(V(g)$name, uninames)) : 
  Cannot substract unknown type from igraph graph
```

It works fine with `keep.all.vertices = T`. While I am not sure what the difference is when I change `keep.all.verticez` from `FALSE` to `TRUE`, I was keeping it at `F` because I was following a tutorial where they did.

The igraph documentation merely says

> `keep.all.vertices`    Logical scalar, whether to keep vertices that
>   only appear in a subset of the input graphs.

I'd like to know what the `keep.all.vertices` flag does, and why having it `F` isn't working for me.

Comment: Hard to tell without more info about your graphs, but it seems like `igraph` does not like some of the names you are using. Would help to see output of `g1`, `g2`, `g3`.

Comment: @paqmo not sure what exactly you want - you want to see the nodes and edges of the graph? I have over 300 edges and 120 vertices in each.

Comment: I'm guessing the issue is in the names, check `class` to make sure they're characters.

Comment: @paqmo yes they are.